# how to import json file having nested json array without keys into mongodb using nodejs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongo and want to Import json file with nested json array without key's but i don't know how to parse a this format and then import to mongodb. Let me Explain-->

Here is Json file that i had converted from PDF file :

```
[  
   [  
      "S. No.",
      "Bank Name",
      "First 4 Letters of ",
      "IFSC",
      "Short Code",
      "Multimodal Code"
   ],
   [  
      "1",
      "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank",
      "ABHY",
      "ACB",
      "*99*87#"
   ],
   [  
      "2",
      "Allahabad Bank",
      "ALLA",
      "ALB",
      "*99*54#"
   ],
   [  
      "3",
      "Andhra Bank",
      "ANDB",
      "ANB",
      "*99*59#"
   ],
   [  
      "4",
      "Apna Sahakari Bank",
      "ASBL",
      "APN",
      "*99*85#"
   ],
   [  
      "5",
      "Axis Bank",
      "UTIB",
      "AXB",
      "*99*45#"
   ]
]
```

now i want to directly import into my mongodb using node.js expect first array that is irreverent:

```
[  
      "S. No.",
      "Bank Name",
      "First 4 Letters of ",
      "IFSC",
      "Short Code",
      "Multimodal Code"
 ]
```

Ok, so after store data in mongodb i want result of find query something like this:

```
{“banks”: [ 
 {“name”: “Abhyudaya Co-op Bank”,  “ifsc”: “ABHY”, “sc”: “ACB”},
 {“name”: “Allahabad Bank”,  “ifsc”: “ALLA”, “sc”: “ALB”}, 
 {“name”: “Andhra Bank”,  “ifsc”: “ANDB”, “sc”: “ANB”},
 {“name”: “Apna Sahakari Bank”,  “ifsc”: “ASBL”, “sc”: “APN”},
 {“name”: “Axis Bank”,  “ifsc”: “UTIB”, “sc”: “AXB”}
 ]}
```

Please help me with node.js code or query to import this file in mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. I did it for only two parameters you please put the others accordingly. put the code inside a .js file. i guess you have to already create a collection 'tmp' (or what you want) in the database with _id:0 (which I matched here) and  "banks":[ ]. I tried to put doc.length in the for loop, somehow it did not work, so I put 5 there.you can try that. check the "tmp" collection after few seconds even if the node command does not end in node.js shell

---

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;var assert = require('assert');var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {

doc = "put your doc here"
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){var a =  doc[i][1];var b =  doc[i][2];db.collection('tmp').update({_id:0},{ "$push" : {"banks" :{"name": a,"ifsc": b}}});}; } 

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) { assert.equal(null, err);insertDocument(db, function() {
  db.close();});});
```

---

[image]

Comment: if you found my answer useful would you mark it correct. thanks.